# How to measure code complexity in powershell?

Tags: powershell-2.0, complexity-theory

We have a bunch of complex code in power shell which we are simplifying. Looking for

tools on measuring the code complexity .
that can be integrated in VSO build system to keep it under control.
Thanks, Lakshay

Answer (score 0):

https://mathieubuisson.github.io/measuring-powershell-code-complexity/ this one seems to be a good solution. In the process  of trying it out.